# How to limit results from database, Spring Data JPA, DB2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

Using a Spring Boot app with JpaRepository to query a DB2 database for the first time.  How would I go about doing a sysout with say the first 20 rows?  Just want to test that I am able to access the table data.  Lastly, this DB2 table has about 24 columns but I'm not seeing a specified primary key on this table.  Using platinum via TSOA to view table data.  I imagine there is a command to find the PK but my research has failed to find the answer.

Comment: Google: "pagination"

Comment: Help me understand the negative points on my reputation so I can avoid in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In Db2 SQL you can use

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

or equivalently

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 20
```

Primary Key columns can be found with SQL such as this (in DB2 11.1 onwards)

```
SELECT 
    TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
,   LISTAGG(COLNAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLSEQ) AS PK_COLS  
FROM 
     SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE KU
JOIN SYSCAT.TABCONST  TC USING ( TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, CONSTNAME )
WHERE
    TC.TYPE = 'P'
GROUP BY
    TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Override
    public List<Passenger> findOrderedBySeatNumberLimitedTo(int limit) {
     return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Passenger p ORDER BY p.seatNumber",
          Passenger.class).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
    }
```